# Error trying to import dump file to Autonomous Database from MINIO using Data Pump

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am trying to import dump files stored in Minio Storage (on premise) to an Autonomous Database and running into the below error. I have already changed the policy of the bucket to Read & Write.

Is it possible import dumpfiles from MINIO Object Storage?

Error:

ORA-31640: unable to open dump file "https://play.min.io/xxx/TEST.dmp" for read

ORA-17503: ksfdopn:11 Failed to open file https://play.min.io/xxx/TEST.dmp

ORA-17500: ODM err:ODM HTTP Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

MINIO is not one of the supported object storage systems. The supported storage systems are listed in the documentation, here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/file-uri-formats.html#GUID-5D3E1614-ADF2-4DB5-B2B2-D5613F10E4FA

This is linked from the Autonomous Database documentation on loading data with Data Pump here; https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/load-data-data-pump.html#GUID-297FE3E6-A823-4F98-AD50-959ED96E6969